# Python Function that creates class instances

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

Hello i want to create a function which creates instances of a class

```
def make_instance(name_instance)
    name_instance=puppy()

class puppy:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name =name

make_instance(cloud) 
# when i pass an argument it says the variable is undefined and i use #isinstance() it return False.
```

Comment: you are calling puppy() and not giving it an argument. it should be name_instance=puppy(some_value)

Answer (score 1):

Your `puppy` class needs to take a `name` value into its constructor, and you're currently not passing in anything.

Also your function doesn't return the instance at all.  It simply re-assigns the instance to the variable `name_instance` that you pass in (losing your input).  The return value of `make_instance` right now is `None`

My guess is that you want your implementation to look like the following

```py
def make_instance(name_instance)
   return puppy(name_instance)
```

I do want to point out though that this function isn't useful unless it does more than just create the instance, you're just adding wrapper code around the constructor

Comment: Ok since this is my first question i made some syntax mistakes , but the flaws you corrected were not what i meant .  What i really need is somone to explain if it is possible to pass a undefined variable ? because i want to name the class and a string can not be a variable so when i pass a undefined variable i get an error.:( thanks for your input though.

Comment: I don't follow your question at all.  What do you mean by "undefined variable"?  And you want to name the class?  Name the class what?